# Why won't my mysql1 queries in dart return any results?

Tags: mysql, dart

I have recently started developing a flutter/dart project getting some basic pages set up and navigation.

I have a MySQL database that I would like to incorporate and I found the mysql1 package to help me do this. I've imported the package and used the examples found [here](https://pub.dev/packages/mysql1).

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to see any of the data in the db.

in my Main.dart I have this:

```
 import 'dart:async';
 import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';

 Future main() async {
   // Open a connection (testdb should already exist)
   final connection = await MySqlConnection.connect(new ConnectionSettings(
     host: '10.0.2.2',
     port: 3306,
     user: 'root',
     password: 'gDrP^6W42f9Z',
     db: 'EntomologyApp',
   ));

   var results = await connection.query('select * from Account'); // expected results
   print(results);

   // Finally, close the connection
   await connection.close();
 }
```

After trying so many different approaches and not reaching any real solution I don't know what to try next.

Here, I expect a connection to made to MySQL DB and the data to be accessed through the `connection.query` select statement. I then expect it to print out the results just so I can clarify there is results.

When I run the exact same query in SQL workbench, I get results of dummy data I have inserted for testing but here all I get in the console is '()' which I would assume is just an empty list of potential records.

Now, I know it may seem like there's a connection issue, but if I put this line of code in just above the other query code:

```
   await connection.query(
       'CREATE TABLE users (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(255), email varchar(255), age int)');
```

it works and creates a 'users' table in workbench, then any time I run after, it will say a table already exists called 'users'. I have this code here just to test that table creation works. I want to access the data in the 'Account' table however, of which there are plenty of records now.

EDIT:
I have now tested inserting a single record with:
`await connection.query('insert into Account (email, password) values ("bob@bob.com", "password123")');`

and it successfully creates a record in the Account table, so creation statements seem to work but select doesn't.

Comment: The table name in your first code sample is "Account" but in your second code sample you're creating table named "users", which table name is the one that contains the records?

Comment: @JorgeZ My bad I should've explained that further. Those are two separate tables. 'users' was just an example table name I used to test table creation. I want to access records in the 'Account' table of which there are many records now.

Comment: When setting up your ConnectionSettings, instead of using host: "10.0.2.2" use host: "localhost" and make sure the port, user, password, and db have the correct values.

Comment: @JorgeZ using localhost as my host gives me an error:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 44634

I had this issue before and discovered that because I'm running the project in an emulator, it needs to use the loopback address (10.0.2.2) to access the localhost machine. In short 10.0.2.2 should be equivalent functionally to localhost.

Also, trying to run localhost on Chrome gives me:
Error: Unsupported operation: RawSocket constructor

Comment: When you tested inserting a single record did you do it in dart code or in IDE/command line?

Comment: I don't know dart or mysql1 but the first step to me would be figuring out how .query and .connect return errors and checking if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have an answer or solution to this problem, during the troubleshooting of this post I played around with using the [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http)
and followed a very insightful straight forward tutorial series by the [CodingCafe on YouTube](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxefhmF0pcPnvPRyQZi8UXptFcKZZ1fkA) which has helped me now create a reliable connection with my Flutter Dart project and my backend SQL database which I've now migrated to a XAMPP server.

Anyone struggling to work with mysql1, I would recommend http as it does seem more flexible to use when working with json payloads.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you would have to change the ConnectionSettings and table name to fit yours, but this code works for me:

```
import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';

Future main(List<String> arguments) async {
  MySqlConnection? con;
  try {
    con = await MySqlConnection.connect(ConnectionSettings(
      host: "localhost",
      port: 3306,
      db: "world",
      user: "root",
      password: null,
      characterSet: CharacterSet.UTF8MB4,
    ));

    Results results = await con.query("SELECT * FROM categories");
    print(results);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  } finally {
    if (con != null) await con.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: I regret to say that in my struggle, I wasn't able to get it working and ultimately gave up on this package. I'm now using http package for API interactions with my SQL server and it works great. Thank you for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Trying the code in [mysql1 page](https://pub.dev/packages/mysql1), i've noticed that it worked on my pc with mariadb installed but not in my mysql pc. Might have something to do with compatibility with the version i'm using but weird anyway.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Flutter's `mysql1` package `query` function doesn't await properly.

For me the results are available when i do this:

```
var results = await conn.query('select * from Foo');
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));          // add this
// handle results
```